# excel get date period were value appears?

Tags: excel, date

i am trying to get the date period using an excel formula

```
=COUNTIF(RawData!D5:D10004,B8)&" - " &TEXT( IFERROR(INDEX(RawData!G5:G10004,MATCH("*"&'Summary of spend_1'!B8&"*",RawData!D5:D10004,0)),"No Details Held"),"dddd mmmm dd,yyyy")
```

I want to count how many times a value is found in my columns and match this with the minimum and maximum date.

for instance supplier a will have been invoiced on 1st September 2014 and 5th September 2014, and the last invoice was 25th September 2014.

so how could I say supplier a had 11 invoices raised between 1st September and 25th September?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume date column is `A:A`, minimum date is in cell `B1`, maximum - in cell `C1`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,">="&$B$1,$A:$A,"<="&$C$1)
```

Comment: so how I would I combine this with my index lookup function?